# Null Reference Exception when Databinding a DataList using VisualBasic.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

As a customer's request, I'm migrating a Web Application that I've built in C# to Visual Basic and I'm having some trouble when trying to Databind a Datalist using a DataTable as Source.

In my original code, in C#, the DataList Databinding works great, but in Visual Basic throws a Null Reference Exception. I've done a step by step debugging and all the used variables are initialized and have data, so I'm wondering if there is a difference in the binding process between C# and Visual Basic.

Here is my original C# Code

```
public void CargarMiniaturas(Imagen iImagen) {
            //I clear the DataList DataSource
            dlMiniaturas.DataSource = null;

            // Number of pages
            int CantPaginas = iImagen.CantidadPaginas;
            //Create DataTable and DataColumn
            DataTable dt = new DataTable( );
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Imagen", typeof(System.String));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            //Fill the data
            for(int i = 0; i <= CantPaginas - 1; i++) {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow( );
                dr[0] = "data:image/gif;base64," + Globales.Imagen_a_Base64(iImagen.GetThumbnail(iImagen, i, new Size(120, 120)));
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            //Load the data into the DataList
            dlMiniaturas.DataSource = dt;
            dlMiniaturas.DataBind( );
            dlMiniaturas.SelectedIndex = _iImagen.iNumPagina;
        }
```

And my Visual Basic Code:

```
 Public Sub CargarMiniaturas(iImagen As Imagen)
            'I clear the DataList DataSource
            dlMiniaturas.DataSource = Nothing

            'Number of pages
            Dim CantPaginas As Integer = iImagen.CantidadPaginas
            'Create Datatable and Datacolumn
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim dc As New DataColumn("Imagen", GetType(System.String))
            dt.Columns.Add(dc)

            'Fill the data
            For i As Integer = 0 To CantPaginas - 1
                Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                dr(0) = "data:image/gif;base64," + Globales.Imagen_a_Base64(iImagen.GetThumbnail(iImagen, i, New Size(120, 120)))
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            Next

            'Load the data into the datalist
            dlMiniaturas.DataSource = dt
            dlMiniaturas.DataBind()    '    Here is where throws the nullreference exception.
            dlMiniaturas.SelectedIndex = _iImagen.iNumPagina
        End Sub
```

In both cases, the parameter **iImagen** contains the custom Object that I'm using, with all it's properties and values. Also, all the variables used in this function have their corresponding values.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to load a Multi Page Tiff image Thumbnails preview into a DataList, using some custom objects, which works perfectly on the C# project.

What I'm doing Wrong??

Some background:

My original solution includes several projects, in which I've isolated in a library all the code needed for the custom Image object (ImageViewer.Lib.dll) and other separate components to visualize the image in Windows Forms, WebForms and Windows Presentation Foundation.

To build the Visual Basic Project Web Visualization I've used references to the ImageViewer.Lib.dll that I've written in C#, so there's no need to rebuild anything but the web viewer.

I'm a Visual Basic newbie, so I've used an Online Code Converter. So far everything works great except this.

Any help or hint you can provide will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake!!
I was using an ItemDataBound event, in which I had:

```
Protected Sub dlMiniaturas_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataListItemEventArgs)
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.SelectedItem Then
            Dim dli As ImageButton = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("imbBtn"), ImageButton)
            dli.Attributes.Add("ident", "btnMiniatura")
            dli.Attributes.Add("index", e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString())
        End If
    End Sub
```

But in the aspx I had commented out the line with the control "imbBtn".

```
   <asp:DataList ID="dlMiniaturas" CssClass="Tabla" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlMiniaturas_ItemDataBound" EnableViewState="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%--<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imbBtn" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Imagen") %>' Width="100" Height="100" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' EnableViewState="false" BackColor="White" ImageAlign="Middle" />--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

So it was MY mistake. 
Uncommenting the line solved the issue.

Anyway, thanks to everyone who spent time reading.